# ¿Cómo se podría hacer la siguiente consulta en ACCESS?

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Tengo las siguientes tablas (TABLA 1 y TABLA 2) y necesito validar los datos de cada cliente en "TABLA 1" con los que refleja "TABLA 2".

Es decir, si el cliente 1 con ese CP, "COMPRA" y tiene el Atributo AA1, es correcto, pues coincide con el atributo de los clientes que compran en ese CP según la tabla 2. Pero, por ejemplo, el cliente 2 es erróneo. Pues un cliente que "VENDE" en el CP 18014 debe tener el atributo "AA2" según la tabla 2. Así que la consulta deberá devolverme este cliente como indico en la imagen.

**TABLA 1**

| CLIENTE | CP | ACTIVIDAD | ATRIBUTO | DEFINICIÓN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18001 | A | AA1 | COMPRA |
| 2 | 18014 | B | AA1 | VENDE |
| 7 | 21500 | A | AA1 | COMPRA |
| 8 | 19500 | A | AA2 | COMPRA |
| 9 | 19260 | B | AA1 | VENDE |
| 12 | 18014 | C | AA3 | ALQUILA |
| 14 | 23014 | B | AA4 | VENDE |
| 17 | 18001 | C | AA5 | ALQUILA |
| 19 | 23005 | D | AA6 | CEDE |

**TABLA 2**

| CP | COMPRA | VENDE | ALQUILA | CEDE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18001 | AA1 | AA2 | AA3 | AA4 |
| 18014 | AA1 | AA2 | AA3 | AA3 |
| 19260 | AA2 | AA3 | AA1 | AA3 |
| 19500 | AA2 | AA6 | AA2 | AA4 |
| 21500 | AA1 | AA4 | AA3 | AA4 |
| 23005 | AA3 | AA4 | AA4 | AA5 |
| 23014 | AA4 | AA4 | AA1 | AA1 |

[image: TABLAS Y RESULTADO ESPERADO CONSULTA]

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Qué has intentado? Necesitamos ver tu código para saber dónde está la inconsistencia. Y, por favor, mejora el título de tu pregunta. Estrictamente hablando, la respuesta a tu pregunta es: "Sí se puede"

Comment: Por favor, no pongas el código en los comentarios. Edita tu pregunta y agrégalo ahí

Comment: Actualizado con código. Disculpa pero ando perdido con consultas más complejas. Muchas gracias de antemano @Arriel

Comment: CP no puede ser clave primaria en la Tabla 3 según tu ejemplo, porque tiene repetido el valor 12001 y el 13001. Las claves primarias deben ser únicas.

Comment: Exacto en la tabla que salgo está mal , habría que quitar repetidos. En la situación real no tengo registros repetidos en CP.

Comment: ¿Ya está resuelto o sigues necesitando ayuda? En el segundo caso, ayudaría que nos dejaras el contenido de las tablas en modo texto para poder copiarlo y hacer pruebas

Comment: @DavidJP Acabo de actualizar y simplificar un poco la consulta. Añado la tabla en texto para ver si así es más sencillo de cara a ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues tienes que dar varios pasos:

En primer lugar, crear las consultas intermedias ALQUILA, CEDE, COMPRA y VENDE así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, las consultas DEVOLUCIONES_ALQUILA, DEVOLUCIONES_CEDE, DEVOLUCIONES_COMPRA y DEVOLUCIONES_VENTAS de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Finalmente, unir las últimas cuatro consultas con:

```
SELECT * FROM DEVOLUCIONES_COMPRA
UNION
SELECT * FROM DEVOLUCIONES_VENTAS
UNION
SELECT * FROM DEVOLUCIONES_CEDE
UNION 
SELECT * FROM DEVOLUCIONES_ALQUILA;
```

Para obtener el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te paso el SQL de todas las consultas intermedias para que puedas reproducirlas:

```
SELECT [Tabla 2].CP, [Tabla 2].ALQUILA AS ATRIBUTO, "ALQUILA" AS DEFINICIÓN
FROM [Tabla 2];
SELECT [Tabla 2].CP, [Tabla 2].CEDE AS ATRIBUTO, "CEDE" AS DEFINICIÓN
FROM [Tabla 2];
SELECT [Tabla 2].CP, [Tabla 2].COMPRA AS ATRIBUTO, "COMPRA" AS DEFINICIÓN
FROM [Tabla 2];
SELECT [Tabla 2].CP, [Tabla 2].VENDE AS ATRIBUTO, "VENDE" AS DEFINICIÓN
FROM [Tabla 2];

SELECT [Tabla 1].*, ALQUILA.ATRIBUTO
FROM [Tabla 1] INNER JOIN ALQUILA ON ([Tabla 1].DEFINICIÓN = ALQUILA.DEFINICIÓN) AND ([Tabla 1].CP = ALQUILA.CP)
WHERE (((ALQUILA.ATRIBUTO)<>[TABLA 1].[ATRIBUTO]));

SELECT [Tabla 1].*, CEDE.ATRIBUTO
FROM [Tabla 1] INNER JOIN CEDE ON ([Tabla 1].DEFINICIÓN = CEDE.DEFINICIÓN) AND ([Tabla 1].CP = CEDE.CP)
WHERE (((CEDE.ATRIBUTO)<>[TABLA 1].[ATRIBUTO]));

SELECT [Tabla 1].*, COMPRA.ATRIBUTO
FROM [Tabla 1] INNER JOIN COMPRA ON ([Tabla 1].DEFINICIÓN = COMPRA.DEFINICIÓN) AND ([Tabla 1].CP = COMPRA.CP)
WHERE (((COMPRA.ATRIBUTO)<>[TABLA 1].[ATRIBUTO]));

SELECT [Tabla 1].*, VENDE.ATRIBUTO AS [ATRIBUTO CORRECTO]
FROM [Tabla 1] INNER JOIN VENDE ON ([Tabla 1].DEFINICIÓN = VENDE.DEFINICIÓN) AND ([Tabla 1].CP = VENDE.CP)
WHERE (((VENDE.ATRIBUTO)<>[TABLA 1].[ATRIBUTO]));
```

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Un millón de gracias. Era justo lo que necesitaba.